# Unable to open shape_predictor_68_face_landmarks.dat

Tags: machine-learning, image-processing, computer-vision, face-detection

I am trying to crop images to detect faces using dlib but I keep getting this error,[The error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/B3ywF.png)

I have downloaded the .dat file in the same directory where the .ipynb file is stored but the issue persists. I downloaded the file from dlib.net.